# How to make a new branch on pull conflict?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a clone of a repo on my localhost and a server. My friend did some changes on the server's copy. However, he didn't commit them.
I worked on my local copy and committed (as well as pushed) the changes to the `master` branch of the repo.

Now, I had to pull the changes on the server and I get :

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    /path/to/files
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I want to pull my chnages to the master branch of local on the server. However, I want to make a new branch in which the friend's work is there.

Or the reverse, i.e. pull my changes on a new branch and let his changes be on the master.

I looked up a few other questions on branching but didn't find a way out. Sorry, I'm new to version control system. So, if there're better ways of handling such issue please do guide me in the right direction.

Comment: try this `git checkout -b newBranchName` - create and switch branch

Comment: I understand I can make new branch like that, but should I stash the changes in one branch and then pull and pull the changes from master in the other ? Or what ? Can I lose data from stash ?

Comment: Is there has a helpful answer for you? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got is caused by you have local changes which are not be committed (you can use `git status` to check).

So first you need to commit/stash the local changes. If you want commit, you can use `git commit -am 'message'`.Now you can pull changes from server to local:

```
git checkout –b friend
git pull origin master
```

**Note:** if there have conflict, you should modify and save the conflict file. Then use `git add filename` and `git commit -am 'merge message'` to finish the merge.

Also you can directly pull server master branch to your local master branch.

Answer (score 0):

> *error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>       /path/to/files
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
>   Aborting*

When you receive this message then you should type:

```
git commit -m "comment here"
```

Then you can push your code.

```
git push origin master
```

Then your code will be push in your branch where you want to marge your code.

Comment: Please don't include your email ID in posts. It could considered as spam and can get your account blocked.

Comment: Okay Tushar, Thanks